# Share Facebook page link Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post Facebook page link from my iPhone app on Facebook but it gave me error

> Error publishing story :The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 102.)

I am using below code:

```
- (void)showShareFbDialog
{
    // Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
    params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/hellothemes"];
    params.name =  @"Title";
    params.caption = @"Caption";
    params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:imageName];
    params.linkDescription = @"Description";

    // If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
        // Present the share dialog

        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                         name:params.name
                                      caption:params.caption
                                  description:params.linkDescription
                                      picture:params.picture
                                  clientState:nil
                                      handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                          if(error) {
                                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                              //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
                                              NSLog(@"Error publishing story :%@", error.localizedDescription);
                                          } else {
                                              // actions to perform
                                          }
                                      }];

    } else {
        // Present the feed dialog

        [self shareLinkWithAPICalls];

    }
}
```

I am using latest Facebook SDK. Kindly help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Do you have a valid permissions? In this case ``publish_actions`` is required. You should share your complete code.

Comment: Yes, I have added that permission in "publish_actions". Do I need to approve this permission from Facebook as they have changed their policies?

Comment: One thing also which I want to mention here is that if I change this line `params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/hellothemes"];` to some other url, publish worked perfect.

Comment: It works for me. Did you define imageName? What about shareLinkWithApiCalls? Like Sudhanshu says, please publish all your code.